# Python subprocess.run cannot execute in chroot

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, python-os, chroot

I have two files, `a.py`:

```
import os, subprocess

os.chroot(".")
subprocess.run(["./b.sh"])
```

and `b.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo whateva
```

in an otherwise empty directory. `b.sh` has executable permission.
Why does `python3 a.py` fail with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/yadda/yadda/a.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 548, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1917, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './b.sh'
```

This is running as root, `uname -a` is `Linux me 6.4.1-arch2-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue, 04 Jul 2023 08:39:40 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux` (I get the same behavior in a Ubuntu Docker container). What am I not understanding? Do I need a shell binary in the chroot?

Thank you!

Comment: os.chroot(".") is changing the root directory to the current directory. So after that, Python/subprocess is looking for b.sh in the new root folder, not the original path.

Try using an absolute path for "b.sh"

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/env` exist in the `chroot`? What about `bash`? If you're running things in a chroot you need to include all the necessary dependencies (which may also include shared libraries).

Comment: @Moid still gives me the same error.

Comment: @larsks that makes sense-- in the context of my project, `a.py` is running in a directory with cross-compiled binaries and libraries for `bash`, `binutils`, `gcc`, `coreutils` a lot of standard stuff. Do you have any idea of how I could figure out what library or binary Python is expecting but missing? Or what component is not working as expected? Right now I'm looking at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_posixsubprocess.c, which I guess is a C module within subprocess.py in python3.10

Comment: What is inside the chroot? Do dynamic libraries needed to run env and bash and echo are inside the chroot? `Do I need a shell binary in the chroot?` Yes, you definitely need many files in the chroot to run shell including the shell binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `env` executable, or it exist in a different path under your chrooted tree (i.e. not under `/usr/env/`). This can be easily demonstrated even without chroot. Let's remove the chroot, and change b.sh as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/no_such_file bash
echo whateva
```

Unix (in my case MacOS, but also Linux) will fail executing no_such_file like so:

```
>>> subprocess.run(["./b.sh"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 505, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './b.sh'
>>>
```

But simply changing it to a valid executable (back to `env`) will load just fine:

```
>>> subprocess.run(["./b.sh"])
whateva
CompletedProcess(args=['./b.sh'], returncode=0)
>>>
```

If you don't need the shell script to be portable, and as you mentioned in a comment that you already have a `bash` cross-compiled binary, you can simply use that instead of `env`, such as `#!/bin/bash`. The path to the binary must be within the chroot environment, so in case it resides elsewhere - make sure to update it accordingly.

Diving a bit deeper, `execve(2)`'s [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) somewhat explains that `ENOENT` is set if the executable cannot be found. I've also found [this page](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8177/13w/notes/000_shell_script_execution.html#typing-errors-on-the-first-line) which might provide a better explanation as to why the failure seems to be related to `b.sh` existence instead of the binary itself.